# Pandas - Create a Integer Primary Key based in string columns - python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a primary key based in string columns in my dataframe

```
Month       Name                   ID
01/01/2020  FileName1 - Example    1
01/02/2020  FileName2 - Example    2
01/03/2020  FileName3 - Example    3
```

[enter image description here][1]

I'm using the hash, but its generating the largest values, I would like that ID was the integer numbers.
This is my code

```
all_data['unique_id'] = all_data._ID.map(hash)
_ID is:::: all_data['_ID'] = all_data['Month'].astype(str) + all_data['Name']
```

Comment: what columns are you hashing here?

Comment: You should override `__hash__` magic method: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: _ID is 
all_data['_ID'] = all_data['Month'].astype(str) + all_data['Name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all_data['unique_id'] = pd.factorize(all_data['_ID'])[0]